# ReactJS unique key constraint

Tags: reactjs

I am building a forum in ReactJS, Node.js, Express.js and MySQL.
Things work well in the back-end and the db.

I want to have several posts per topic. Now I am testing and I have two topics and each should have one post.
But all posts go to each topic instead as you can see in the image bellow.

[Posts test page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5YBH.jpg)

The issue is there because React has a unique key constraint.
All the posts from Topic one will have one identical element, in my case the title, which I have to use as a key for the list of posts.
But that gives me the error, that I should have a unique key.

You will find bellow a screenshot of the code:
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG56I.jpg)

I don’t know how to get around this key constraint, nor do I see another solution.

If someone could help, many many thanks.

Have a nice day,
Ana

Comment: Please post the relevant code where the posts are mapped

Comment: NeERAJ TK Thank you, will do.

Comment: @AjeetShah I do have an id and I can get the posts from the db, I just can't  separate them per topic

Comment: In this case, i usually make child ids using a combination of parent `ID` and something unique from child. E,g, child's key: `parentID + childItem.title`